# Type 'number | undefined' is not assignable to type 'number', typescript error?

Tags: typescript

```
function example(queue: number[]): number[] {

    const curLength: number = queue.length
    for (let i = 0; i < curLength; i++) {
        **const cur: number = queue.shift()**
    };

}
```

The error is where the asterisks is. Having an if statement to check for undefined would be redundant because it's pretty clear looking at the code that `cur` cant be `undefined` since I iterate on the length of the queue.

What is the appropriate thing to do in this case to solve the error ?

Comment: Tip: your question will be easier to read and to work with if you use comments to point out things in your code instead of asterisks. Example: `// this next line is where the error happens`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that `shift()` can return either the element (a `number`), or `undefined` if the array is empty ([source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift)). In this case, it has the signature `shift() : number | undefined`. A good IDE, or the [Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org), will tell you this.

The compiler isn't able to figure out that the statement won't be executed if the array is empty, so it still accounts for the case where `shift()` would return `undefined`. But if, as a developer, you are convinced that your program is correct, you can tell the compiler that you know that this function call will never return `undefined` by appending a `!` (the "non-null assertion operator", more info [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#non-null-assertion-operator)) to the offending expression:

```
const cur: number = queue.shift()!;
```

Either that, or change the type of `cur`:

```
const cur : number | undefined = queue.shift();
```